# Set ListViewItem DataContext to Parent ListViewItem

Tags: xaml, listview, uwp

I have a collection of items in a `ListView`. Each of these items has a collection of tags (as strings) in it. In the `DataTemplate` for each item I have another `ListView` which has the collection of tags:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Items, Mode=OneWay}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:Item">
            <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind Tags, Mode=OneWay}" Grid.Row="1">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Border Background="{x:Bind TagBackgroundColor}" RequestedTheme="Dark">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

My problem is that the `TagBackgroundColor` I'm trying to use on my `Border` is actually a property on the `Item`, not the tag itself. Obviously this doesn't work since the `DataContext` is set to the tag. Is there a way to access the property on the `Item` from inside the tag's `ListViewItem`?

Comment: `RelativeSource FindAncestor` binding is not supported in uwp app, I think you need to change your `Item` and `Tags` model.